# Android: adding child of TableLayout under previously added childview (new line)

Tags: java, android, grid-layout, tablelayout, custom-lists

I hope my question is not too vague.

I have problem that I have been stuck for more than a couple of days. I have searched alot and despite the effort I have not found the solution.

My problem is the following:

I have a TableLayout and I populate my data dynamically with the total amount of items I have in my ArrayList. Momentarily my screen looks like this:

[image]

But what I would like to have is the following:

[image]

I have tried alot of different options for instance:

- Custom list adapter
- TableLayout
- GridLayout
- Alot of setLayoutParams options

Due to my effort and code that I have I would like to stick with TableLayout. GridLayout or any other ..Layout is also not a problem.

```
public void getTableLayoutDinnerProducts() {
    tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutDinner);
    //gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayoutDinner);
    //gridLayout.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
    //gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
    //gridLayout.setRowCount(3);
    //TableLayout.LayoutParams newTableLayout = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //newTableLayout.setMargins(400, 0, 0, 0);

    // Creating a table row for each product in productController.
    for (final Product product : productController.getStaticProducts()) {
        if(product.getCategoryType() == CategoryType.Dinner){

            // Create tablerows
            tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setId(product.getID() + 1);
            tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new Toolbar.LayoutParams(300, 300));

            // Create content for tablerows
            textArray = new TextView(this);
            textCaloriesArray = new TextView(this);
            textProductArray = new TextView(this);

            // Add image for each row
            image = new ImageView(this);

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), product.getImage());
            int width=400;
            int height=400;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
            image.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
            image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.productimages));
            //image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagestyle);
            image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            tableRow.addView(image, 0, new TableRow.LayoutParams(400, 400));

            textArray.setText(product.getName());
            textCaloriesArray.setText(" Cal: " + String.valueOf(product.getCalories()));
            textProductArray.setText(" Prod: " + String.valueOf(product.getProductType()));
            textArray.setTextSize(18);
            textArray.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            textArray.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textArray.setPadding(0, 150, 0, 100);

            //TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams)textArray.getLayoutParams();
            //params.span = 4;
            //textArray.setLayoutParams(params); // causes layout update

            tableRow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.productimages));
            tableRow.addView(textArray, 1, new TableRow.LayoutParams(200, 500));
            tableRow.addView(textCaloriesArray, 2, new TableRow.LayoutParams(200, 400));
            tableRow.addView(textProductArray, 3, new TableRow.LayoutParams(200, 400));

            tableRow.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    final View background = v;
                    background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DinnerScreen.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
                    dialog.show();

                    dismisspopup = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dismissPopup);
                    dismisspopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            background.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.productimages));
                        }
                    });

                    removeproduct = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.removeProduct);
                    removeproduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DinnerScreen.class);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            products = productController.getStaticProducts();
                            products.remove(product);
                            productController.setStaticProducts(products);
                            productController.getStaticProducts();

                            intent.putExtra("totalProducts", products);
                            intent.putExtra("totalCalories", String.valueOf(calorieCounter.getCountcalories()));
                            overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
                            showToastMessage("Product has been removed");
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                }
            });

            tableRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    calorieCounter.addCalories(product.getCalories());
                    changeStatusBar(calorieCounter.getCountcalories());
                }
            });
            //gridLayout.addView(tableRow);
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
}
```

Because I add these dynamically I don't have an .XML file to add the width or position.

There must be a solution for this problem. Only I cannot find it anymore.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any specific requirement you adding views runtime not using xml, for above view you can simply use recyclerview else using your approach it will be messy and complex because you have to first crate one layout then add all textview to layout and add final layout to tablerow or simply add inflated xml view to table row,

Comment: Whilst making this I had no specific requirement. When I made some progress over the days I noticed that this was not the best approach. Basically I done with my app, but the layout is the only thing bugging me right now. So I thought maybe there is a simple solution to fix the layout, that I am overseeing. But you suggest a recyclerview?

Comment: yes recyclerview is faster and efficient to handle large data where TableLayout is not recommended for this it will better you switch to recyclerview but its up to you if you want to use same approach you have to  create on xml add that runtime in table row.